# How to reduce the exported pdf file size in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, pdf

My org file consists of mainly images. The exported latex is ~60MB. Currently I'm using a subsequent `ghostcript` shell script to shrink the pdf's filesize to ~6MB. Does emacs offer some hidden superpower to achieve a similar result after exporting e.g. `org exported pdf hook`[0] ?

[0] pseudocode

Comment: Did you see the  answer to this question? Did you try it? Did it work? Inquiring minds ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your shell script is called `pdf-compact` and is invoked with the name of the PDF file:

```sh
pdf-compact myfile.pdf
```

It may replace `myfile.pdf` with a new version (maybe saving the original for safety until you are satisfied that it is safe), or it may produce a new file, say `myfile-C.pdf` (`C` for `compact`).

You can modify the `org-latex-pdf-process` variable like this:

```el
(add to-list 'org-latex-pdf-process "pdf-compact %b.pdf" t)
```

The last argument `t` says to add the new element at the end of the list `org-latex-pdf-process`. The `%b` is replaced by the file base name (e.g `myfile` in the example above).

See the doc string of `org-latex-pdf-process` (`C-h v org-latex-pdf-process`) for other replacement values that are triggered by a `%b`-like mechanism.

Untested.